# Package multibib problem with IEEEtran

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, multibib

I am using the IEEEtran template, and I have to separate the list of references into two lists, one main references list and one in the appendix. I am using the `multibib` package, but the second one in the appendix appears empty.

Sample of the document:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
  \newcites{PS}{Studies}

 \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \makeatletter
     \patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
      \section*{\refname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}}{}{}{}
       \makeatother

     \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
     \usepackage[english]{babel}

      \usepackage{enumitem}
      \usepackage{url}
      \usepackage{hyperref}

 \begin{document}
 \title{Title goes here}
 \author{ABC}
  \IEEEtitleabstractindextext{
  \begin{abstract}
   abstract goes here...
 \end{abstract}
 \maketitle

  \section{Introduction}
  Lorum ipsum....
  main reference citation \cite{gamma}
  appendix reference citation \citePS{cook}

  \appendices
  \section{}
   \bibliographystyleS{plainyr}
   \bibliographyS{PS-bib}

 \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
  \bibliography{references-bib}


   \end{document}
```

Compilation:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ paperdraft, PS ] }
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
```

Sample of main bibliography:

```
@article{gamma,
title = {Gamma, alpha, delta, and theta oscillations govern cognitive         processes},
volume = {39},
number = {2-3},
journal = {International Journal of Psychophysiology},
author = {Basar, Erol and {Basar-Eroglu}, Canan and Karakas, Sirel and    Schürmann, Martin},
month = jan,
year = {2001},
pages = {241--248},
}
```

Sample of appendix references:

```
 @ARTICLE{cook,
 author = {Cook, D.J. and Augusto, J.C. and Jakkula, V.R.},
 title = {Ambient intelligence: Technologies, applications, and opportunities},
  journal = {Pervasive and Mobile Computing},
 year = {2009},
  volume = {5},
  pages = {277--298},
 number = {4}
}
```

Comment: Your reputation points are now high enough you are allowed to vote up helpful answers. Please consider to do this with the answer below. It is the way to say "Thank You" here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code are some errors, for example did you not close command `\IEEEtitleabstractindextext{` with `}` and I corrected `\bibliographyS`/`\bibliographystyleS` to `\bibliographyPS`/`\bibliographystylePS`.

I used package `filecontents` to create a compilable MWE, containing the given tex code (corrected) and both bib files. Copy the following MWE please to your computer and name it `399998.tex`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{399998-main.bib}
@article{gamma,
  title = {Gamma, alpha, delta, and theta oscillations govern cognitive         processes},
  volume = {39},
  number = {2-3},
  journal = {International Journal of Psychophysiology},
  author = {Basar, Erol and {Basar-Eroglu}, Canan and Karakas, Sirel and    Schürmann, Martin},
  month = jan,
  year = {2001},
  pages = {241--248},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{399998-ref.bib}
@ARTICLE{cook,
  author = {Cook, D.J. and Augusto, J.C. and Jakkula, V.R.},
  title = {Ambient intelligence: Technologies, applications, and opportunities},
  journal = {Pervasive and Mobile Computing},
  year = {2009},
  volume = {5},
  pages = {277--298},
  number = {4},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{PS}{Studies}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
  \patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
    \section*{\refname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\title{Title goes here}
 \author{ABC}
  \IEEEtitleabstractindextext{test} % <=================================
  \begin{abstract}
   abstract goes here...
 \end{abstract}
 \maketitle

  \section{Introduction}
  Lorum ipsum....
  main reference citation \cite{gamma}
  appendix reference citation \citePS{cook}

\appendices
\section{test}
\bibliographystylePS{plainyr} % <=======================================
\bibliographyPS{399998-ref} % <=========================================

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{399998-main} % <==========================================

\end{document}
```

Open the terminal and execute the following commands:

```
pdflatex 399998.tex
```

Now you got two files `399998.aux` and `PS.aux`. Now you can use bibtex for both `aux` files:

```
bibtex 399998.aux
bibtex PS.aux
```

Now we need to compile the TeX file two times to get correct tableofcontents, pages etc:

```
pdflatex 399998.tex
pdflatex 399998.tex
```

After that steps I get the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting page 2]

Comment: Where is the MWE, please? :)

Comment: @bers Ups, sorry, added ...